# Issue with Insert function in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, gridview

This is my code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = constr;
        con.Open();

        string str1 = "Insert into SuperCars(Car ,mph,price) Values ('" + textBox2.Text + "'," + textBox3.Text + ",'" + textBox4.Text + "' )";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted successfully.");
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        label5.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

I want to insert data in my GridView. When I execute this it inserted the data in my database, but it didn't show up in my GridView ... How can I edit it?

Comment: The code above doesn't fill any GridView. It only inserts into the database. So you need to add a call to the code that actually fills your GridView, and it would be best if you also added it to your question.

Comment: Here is link try to bind the grid using it [here][1]


  [1]: http://www.csharptutorial.in/2013/09/CNet-GridView-Example-How-To-Bind-Gridview-in-Asp.net-using-SQLDataSource-at-Design-time.html#.Ut6VUo66ZwA

Comment: You need to be careful Little Bobby Tables doesn't get entered into that text box (http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload your GridView by setting its DataSource again.

```
superCarsGridView.DataSource = null;
superCarsGridView.DataSource = GetSuperCars();
```

EDIT: testing my code, I had an issue rebinding the list on the DataGridView. I got around this by setting the DataSource to null then again setting to the real DataSource.